# Swift 2.0 Escaping string for new line (String Encoding)

Tags: string, swift, encoding, swift2, ios9

I am trying to escape string for new line i.e \n. 
For example lets say string is:-

```
First Line Of String
second Line of String
Third Line of String
```

Now if i use String extension and say

```
func escapeString() -> String{
newString =   self.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding
return newString
}
```

This extension does not give me newString as

```
First Line Of String\nSecond Line Of String\nThird Line Of String
```

I need above string as a jsonString to pass to server.i.e. i have to String encode it

Comment: maybe, i don't understand your needs, but let js = "{\"alfa\":true\n\"beta\":false}" is valid JSON. try to print it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stringByRemovingPercentEncoding` is for [*percent encoding* as used in URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), as you might expect from the name. (If not from that, maybe from reading [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByRemovingPercentEncoding), the pertinent part of which even shows up in Xcode code completion.) That is, it takes a string like "some%20text%20with%20spaces" and turns it into "some text with spaces".

If you want to do a different kind of character substitution, you'll need to do it yourself. But that can still be a one-liner:

```
extension String {
    var withEscapedNewlines: String {
        return self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "\\n")
    }
}
```

Note the first argument to `self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` is an escape code passed to the Swift compiler, so the actual value of the argument is the newline character (ASCII/UTF8 0x0A). The second argument escapes the backslash (in the text passed to the Swift compiler), so the actual value of the argument is the text `\n`.

Comment: Swift 3: `extension String {
    var withEscapedNewlines: String {
 return self.replacingOccurrences(of:"\n", with:"\\n")
    }
}`

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5**

You can use `JSONEncoder` to escape \n, \, \t, \r, ', " and etc. characters instead of manually replacing them in your string e.g.:

```swift
extension String {
    var escaped: String {
        if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) {
            let escaped = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
            // Remove leading and trailing quotes
            let set = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\"")
            return escaped.trimmingCharacters(in: set)
        }
        return self
    }
}

let str = "new line - \n, quote - \", url - https://google.com"
print("Original: \(str)")
print("Escaped: \(str.escaped)")
```

Outputs:

```
Original: new line - 
, quote - ", url - https://google.com
Escaped: new line - \n, quote - \", url - https:\/\/google.com
```